# Do I have to use logistic regression for data that had binary repeated measures?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, modeling, binary-data

I have a dataset that consisted of 0s and 1s originally, where I measured movement (yes or no) per time interval in individual tadpoles. They were grown in different conditions (density treatment groups), which is my main fixed predictor, along with body size, temperature etc. I wanted to have one "activity" value per individual so I averaged the 0s and 1s to get one value. Then I used logit transformations, and conducted linear mixed models (I have one random effect variable) on this dataset to determine the effect density (and other fixed predictors) on "activity".

Is this method of analysis OK, or must I use logistic regressions on the original binary dataset? Is it bad practice to conduct statistics using these "means"?

Comment: Say your data for individual 1 is, [0, 0, 1, 1, 1] --> mean = prop = 0.6. This is binomial data; hence you should be using logistic regression. You can get away with regular regression, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Here's a reference https://www.statistics.ma.tum.de/fileadmin/w00bdb/www/czado/lec3.pdf

Comment: Another http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c3.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Jon , I was wondering though if I use logit transformations on the proportion data, using linear models would be OK

Comment: What do your residuals (studentized) look like?

Comment: @Jon [link] (http://imgur.com/a/hET4E)

Comment: Yeah, I'd say go for it. Just run some diagnostics on the residuals, but it should be fine.